# SSAS Calculated measure with SCOPE.

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2016

I'm building an SSAS OLAP cube on Meteorological data. Some of this data can be totaled (eg rainfall) and some can't (like wind direction).

I want totals, but only on data sources where it makes sense. (Where the interpolation method = 3.)

I've tried adding SCOPE with this:

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Total]); 
SUM([Data Source].[Interpolation Method].&[3],[Measures].[Total]); 
END SCOPE;
```

And get warnings:

> Invalid query syntax. A valid MDX or DAX query was expected

and:

> One or more errors were encountered in the MDX script

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your SSAS database so I can't test the syntax, but I believe you would need to write your MDX as follows (notice the `THIS=` addition):

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Total]); 
THIS = SUM([Data Source].[Interpolation Method].&[3],[Measures].[Total]); 
END SCOPE;
```

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms145989.aspx) for syntax details.

Answer (score 1):

Some measures, even though they are numeric, makes no sense as SUM. 
Temp, Datekey (could be numeric) and others. 
The solution is to mark this measure as non-aggregate in the measure tab. This way it won't be aggregated.